# How to correctly share a ViewModel Delegate between different ViewModels?

Tags: android, delegates, android-viewmodel, dagger-hilt

In my app I have a ViewModel Delegate that is shared between some ViewModels of mine (in the span of a Navigation Graph).

Example: *A ViewModelDelegate that fetches the filter items only once and receives user interaction events in a Navigation Graph that contains two screens (FirstScreen and SecondScreen), where each screen has its own ViewModel (not shared).*

```
interface FilterViewModelDelegate {

    val filterItems: StateFlow<FilterItem>

    fun initFilterViewModelDelegate(
        savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle,
        viewModelScope: CoroutineScope
    )

    fun onFilterItemClicked(filterItemId: String)
}

class FilterViewModelDelegateImpl : FilterViewModelDelegate {

    private lateinit var savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle
    private lateinit var viewModelScope: CoroutineScope

    private val _filterItems = MutableStateFlow<FilterItem>(emptyList())
    override val filterItems = _filterItems.asStateFlow()

    override fun initFilterViewModelDelegate(
        savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle,
        viewModelScope: CoroutineScope
    ) {
        this.savedStateHandle = savedStateHandle
        this.viewModelScope = viewModelScope

        // fetch the filter items and so on
    }

    override fun onFilterItemClicked(filterItemId: String) {
        // implementation...
    }

    // implementation...
}
```

```
@HiltViewModel
class FirstViewModel @Inject constructor(
    savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle,
    filterViewModelDelegate: FilterViewModelDelegate
) : ViewModel(), FilterViewModelDelegate by filterViewModelDelegate {

    init {
        initFilterViewModelDelegate(
            viewModelScope = viewModelScope,
            savedStateHandle = savedStateHandle
        )

        // implementation...
    }

    // implementation...
}

@HiltViewModel
class SecondViewModel @Inject constructor(
    savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle,
    filterViewModelDelegate: FilterViewModelDelegate
) : ViewModel(), FilterViewModelDelegate by filterViewModelDelegate {

    init {
        initFilterViewModelDelegate(
            viewModelScope = viewModelScope,
            savedStateHandle = savedStateHandle
        )

        // implementation...
    }

    // implementation...
}
```

Is this a good way to share the functionality and the data from a specific part of the ViewModel?

**if so**, what would be the correct way to set up the Dagger Hilt for that example?

**If not**, what would you recommend?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a good way to share something long living between shorter living objects.

Can you just add `@Singleton` annotation to `FilterViewModelDelegate` for the ViewModels to share the same instance?